# C# How to declare the void to void?Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'void'

Tags: c#

Sorry,I need explain my initial goal.
I need dynamic call the different void in different class.

```
WorkListDal ad = new WorkListDal();
var model = new WorkListEntity()
model.Formid="WorkList";
model.AfterAuditVoid() = ad.WorkListVoid();
InitWorkListDal.DoWork(model)

WorkListDal2 ad2 = new WorkListDal();
var model = new WorkListEntity()
model.Formid="WorkList";
model.AfterAuditVoid() = ad2.OtherVoid();
InitWorkListDal.DoWork(model)
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'void'

One Entity:

```
public class WorkListEntity
{
  public string Formid { get; set; }
  public void AfterAuditVoid() {}
}
```

One Class:

```
public class WorkListDal
{
   public void WorkListVoid()
   {
     //omit
   }
}
```

One public Class:

```
public class InitWorkListDal
{ 
   public class DoWork(WorkListEntity wf)
   {
     //omit

     //after all call the void.
     wf.AfterAuditVoid();
   }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to assign the value of a method that doesn't return a value to another method?

Comment: You cannot not do that. Because void type does not return any value.

Comment: Why you want to do that, what is your initial goal ?

Comment: How to dynamic call the AfterAuditVoid() to different void?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you wanted to achieve because your code is trying to do something impossible on the face of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model.AfterAuditVoid() = ad.WorkListVoid();
```

There's so much wrong with that line. First, you cannot assign a value to a method.

For example, these will all fail to build:

```
object.Equals() = 0;
String.Join("") = 0;
Int32.Parse("") = 0;
```

At the class level, only writable fields and settable properties can be assigned a value/reference:

```
public String MyProperty { get; set; }
...
obj.MyProperty = "MyValue";
```

I suggest reading over the [MSDN documentation regarding assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) and the [documentation reagarding C# statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143.aspx).

Now, there's a second fallacy aside from trying to assign a value to a method - your attempt to assign a void return type. You can't. There is no return. That is what void means. As in, even if you attempted to set to a property, this still won't work:

```
obj.MyProperty = ad.WorkListVoid();
```

Void simply has no result. It performs a function with no return, so there's no way to assign a void return type. It's different from the concept of `NULL`, so don't confuse `void` with `NULL`.

EDIT:

You might be attempting something else entirely - you might be trying to say "If I call `AfterAuditVoid`, that should actually be calling `WorkListVoid`". We can do that:

```
public class WorkListEntity
{
  public string Formid { get; set; }
  //change to an action (e.g. in lambda terms, this would be () => {} - no parameters and no outputs
  public Action AfterAuditVoid { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you could do:

```
var model = new WorkListEntity()
model.Formid="1";
model.AfterAuditVoid = ad.WorkListVoid;
```

This will allow you to call `model.AfterAuditVoid()`, which will actually be calling `ad.WorkListVoid()`. I suggest reading over [this to get more familiar with funcs and actions](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff0d0f/action-and-func-delegates-in-C-Sharp-net/).

Comment: public Action AfterAuditVoid { get; set; }   it's can set a default Action?

Comment: Using c#-4.0, you would have to use a constructor or a backing field. E.G: `public Action AfterAuditVoid { get { return _myField ?? ( _myField = MyDefaultAction ); } set { return _myField = value; } }`

Answer (score 0):

After the fact that your methods do not return anything, so you can not use their return types in an assignments, even they would have returned something, this would be also wrong, because the both values would be rvalues so you could not assign one to another, both of them will be unreferenced this way, and eligible for garbadge collection, if you don, t hold other references to them. This is simply a wrong way pf thinking.

I suggest you to simple call your methods one after another:

```
 model.AfterAuditVoid();
 ad.WorkListVoid();
```

as in the current moment the assignation, again, even the methods would return, will not took place.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I gather that you want to assign the void function *behavior* to your class function.

Your approach is wrong....perhaps using [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx) is the right approach here. If you do such a modification...you can make your code dynamically reference different functions...even those of void type.